# QT 5.9 mac installation dose not install webkit

Tags: c++, macos, qt, webkit, qt5.9

I want to create a QML project with webkit support therefore I use `QT += webkit` option to load this module but I face with this error at compile time:

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
```

I was installed QT 5.9 on mac OS from installer package. At the installer dialog steps I checked webkit item in package and the installation successfully finished without any problem.

I tried to find out any *webkit*.so or any symbol to ensure this package is exists but I didn't find anything and it seems like this part of package is not installed correctly. Is there any idea to why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Qt Webkit was Deprecated in qt 5.5 at July 2015.

Check [Qt version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_version_history)

You should use WebEngine:

`QT += webenginewidgets`

More info about Porting from Qt WebKit to Qt WebEngine [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)

Comment: I tried using `QT += webenginewidgets` on Mac but it could't find the module. However, it works just fine on Windows.